# What is equalivent C# code from this VB.Net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have the following snippet in VB.Net (web application):

```
Dim lnkTemp as HyperLink = dvFileInfo.FindControl("lnkPlan")
```

dfFileInfo is a DetailsView control from System.Web.UI.WebControls

When I try to convert this to C# like this:

```
HyperLink lnkTemp = dvFileInfo.FindControl("lnkPlan");
```

I get an error after the "=" that states:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink'.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)*

What do I need to do to correct this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also do 'HyperLink lnkTemp = dvFileInfo.FindControl("lnkPlan") as HyperLink' if you don't want it to throw on a bad conversion.  Using the 'as' will cause it to return null if the conversion is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast it:

```
HyperLink lnkTemp = (HyperLink)dvFileInfo.FindControl("lnkPlan");
```

Or be a little safer:

```
HyperLink lnkTemp = dvFileInfo.FindControl("lnkPlan") as HyperLink;
// check for lnkTemp == null
```

The writer of the VB code should probably have been doing the following for clarity:

```
Dim lnkTemp As HyperLink = DirectCast(dvFileInfo.FindControl("lnkPlan"), HyperLink)
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be simple.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add an explicit cast:

```
HyperLink lnkTemp = (HyperLink)dvFileInfo.FindControl("lnkPlan");
```

Comment: Thank You!  You guys were a minute apart.

Comment: I saw his at "2 seconds ago" when mine said "0 seconds ago". Close race! :)